# parentNode Class Not Removing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to remove a class from the parent `<span>` of the current node. I named current node as rows. When console `rows.parentNode` getting `DOMTokenList["checked"`] . How can I remove `checked` class from it?

I have tried `rows.parentNode.classList.remove("checked")` but its not working.

HTML

```
<span class="checked">
        <input type="checkbox" data-orginal="14" data-vxp="50" value="14" data-amount="75" name="expenses" class="old_expenses">
</span>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you clarify precisely in what way it isn't working?

Comment: currentnode.parent().removeClass("checked")?

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/qawihinejo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: `classList` is suppored only by IE 10+, may be this is the reason?

Comment: What browser(s) is this a problem in? I ask because there's a couple of down-voted answers that seem like they should be correct, and I don't know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @DavidThomas I downvoted the answers because they entirely ignored the focus of the question (the `classList` interface), not because they didn't work.

Comment: @lonesomeday: which is understandable, the lack of explanation merited the down-votes; but I wasn't sure if they were -at least partially- from the OP (they didn't solve the problem) or not. The question itself, of course, still lacks sufficient detail, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I called `uniform()` after `rows.parentNode.classList.remove("checked")` to update the list.

```
$('#checkbox').find('input[type=checkbox]').uniform();
```

After removing its working perfectly.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

`classList` returns a DOMTokenList which can be used to add/remove classes to the element. But as you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist), its supported only in latest browsers.

I suggest you use jQuery to do this

```
var $parent = $(rows.parentNode);
if( $parent.hasClass('checked') ){
   $parent.removeClass('checked');
}
```

If you know that `checked` class is always there, you can skip that if condition as well.

If you want to use only javascript, i suggest you do something like this

```
var  parent = rows.parentNode,
     classNames = parent.className;
var newList = classNames.replace('checked','');
parent.className = newList;
```

Hope this helps :)